# Mutable references in rust and `&mut`

Tags: rust, reference, immutability, mutable

So I am reading through The Rust Programming Language book. Specifically, in this [section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#adding-a-key-and-value-only-if-a-key-isnt-present) it says the code

```
    scores.entry(String::from("Blue")).or_insert(50);
```

"returns a mutable reference to the value", so my assumption is that I can do this:

```
    let &mut reff = scores.entry(String::from("Blue")).or_insert(50);
    *reff += 1;
```

Since `&mut` is supposed to be a mutable reference. However, when I do that I get this error:

```
error[E0614]: type `{integer}` cannot be dereferenced
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     *reff += 1;
  |     ^^^^^
```

Anyone know why?

Interestingly if I just do:

```
    let reff = scores.entry(String::from("Blue")).or_insert(50);
    *reff += 1;
```

It works.